# Trying to use '' npm install" on company system. getting the following error

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I am working on an Angular project and I cloned it from Git. While I was installing npm dependencies, I got the following error:

```
npm ERR! code ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! errno ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fmaterial failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 104.16.16.35:443
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\index.js:68:14)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:315:20)
npm ERR!     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:426:9)
npm ERR!     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
npm ERR!     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
npm ERR!  FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fmaterial failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 104.16.16.35:443
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\index.js:68:14)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:315:20)
npm ERR!     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:426:9)
npm ERR!     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
npm ERR!     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
npm ERR!   type: 'system',
npm ERR!   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   parent: 'ClientPerformance'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that the packages repositories are blocked by your company's proxy.

Contact you admin and ask for the remote npm registry.
Then create a `.npmrc` in your root directory. There you can set your company's npm registry. Something like this:

```
registry = <your remote-npm here>
strict-ssl = false
```

Comment: i'll try. Thanks